# The Tiny For Loop that will End Me

Tags: for-loop, google-sheets

I am brand new to coding, and I cannot for the life of me, through any amount of voodoo or googling, understand why this simple code will not work in Google Scripts:

```
var student = new Object; // name & student's hours
var studentNames = new Array;

for (var i=0; i <= allSheets[1].getLastRow(); i++); {
   studentNames[i] = allSheets[1].getRange((i+3),1).getValue();
   student[studentNames[i]] = allSheets[1].getRange(i+3, 3).getValue();
}
```

For some strange reason it just fills the array studentNames with "null", and the Object student will only show one key.

If I bypass the for loop like so,

```
studentNames[0] = allSheets[1].getRange(3,1).getValue();
studentNames[1] = allSheets[1].getRange(4,1).getValue();
studentNames[2] = allSheets[1].getRange(5,1).getValue();
studentNames[3] = allSheets[1].getRange(6,1).getValue();
```

everything works perfectly!

If someone could tell me what I am doing wrong I would be much obliged.

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: Have you checked what allSheets[1].getLastRow() actually returns?

Comment: @doc Yeah, it returns 23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the semicolon at the end of your `for` loop

`for (var i=0; i <= allSheets[1].getLastRow(); i++);` <- this one

cheers : )

Comment: You beat me by two minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra semicolon on line 4:

```
for (var i=0; i <= allSheets[1].getLastRow(); i++); {
```

should be:

```
for (var i=0; i <= allSheets[1].getLastRow(); i++) {
```

The semicolon ends up closing the body of the for loop, so the block `{...}` ends up executing only once.